# Change WebDav permissions for creating files and folders

Tags: permissions, default, webdav

Files and folders created through webdav are assigned `www-data.www-data` and permission `740`. I've already added my user to the `www-data group`, but I'd like to change the permission to `770`, so I can modify them after they are created, without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out:

1. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars`
2. Include the following at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   umask 006
   ```
3. After that restart Apache (`sudo services apache2 restart`)

This will create files with `660` and folders with `770` permission, if uploaded through WebDav.